# Vertex Count Mismatch Error

Tags: animation

I created garments on clo3d and my avatar on Daz3d. I exported my animation in .MDD format.  I then imported that into clo3d and it animated the garment pretty well. Then I exported the animation to point cache format from clo3d to blender.
So I go to blender import my obj and I made sure to select  Keep vertex order. I then go to apply the mesh cache modifier but I keep getting this “ vertex count mismatch” error I’ve been trying for 6/7 hours. Any suggestions or assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Please help

Comment: you need to check "keep vert order" when you import the OBJ. That should do it. Cheers,
Schirin